# How do I set up my system to Always use the global namespace version of a class?

Tags: php, namespaces

## Background

I'm rather new to namespaces. Up to this point I have always used prefixed function names like: `getUserRecord` or `updateUserRecord` instead of `User\getRecord`, etc.

My application is getting rather unruly and names rather long so I am converting an isolated portion of my application as a trial to see if it solves the problem.

## The problem

My first major annoyance is I have several global classes that are used in nearly every single file. e.g `new \Form` . So at the top of all the files I've converted so far I have `use Form;`. This skips using `\` before every occurrence in that file but I still have 10k files that need to be updated and as this specific class will always be used is their a way to declare once in my bootstrap file to always use that global class?

To clarify the `use Form;` is not the only global class. There are also about 20 `FormItem` classes, a dozen `HTMLTemplate` classes and various others. So every file would have 10-50 use statements depending on which ones I'm using on a given file. Is this normal for a namespaced project? I really don't want to have my first  50 lines of every file use statements.

As a bonus I need PHPStorm to recognize that the global is always used so I don't get warnings.

## My ideas

I tried to add the use statements to the bootstrap that obviously does not work as the use statement is scoped to the file.

I can write a function to create a class instance for me as functions do fallback to the global scope automagically. e.g.

```
function getNewForm($name)
{
  return new Form($name);
}
```

This does work but I'm not a fan of it.

Comment: you can suppress warnings by right clicking the warned/error'd block

Comment: @treyBake Thanks for the feedback. I know I can suppress the warning in PHPStorm but that doesn't fix the core issue. I would still need to perform the import for the compiler to identify the correct class.

Comment: Good question, but I think the best route would be a script which amends all your 10k PHP files...

Comment: @lufc that would be very unfortunate. The `Form` class has about 20 `FormItem` classes that would need to be appended with it. Not to mention all the html formatting template classes. This would make namespaces almost unusable to have the first 40 lines of every file these use statements.

Comment: In PHP 7+ you can import multiple classes from a namespace in one line. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.group

Comment: PhpStorm has code folding settings - you can fold imports by default, so you don't need to scroll them every time when you open a file. But if so many classes uses these 20 `FormItem` classes directly (or large number of import overall), this may suggest some design issues and insufficient encapsulation.